# "the more" without the second comparative

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Quotation from the press:

> *Dr Christopher Hand, a lecturer in cyberpsychology, says the more details people disclose, the less sympathy we express when things go
> wrong. This could be due to a belief that **we attract our own
> negative experiences the more we share them**. It seems that
> sadfishing, the idea of searching for sympathy by oversharing, is
> generally perceived as negative rather than the cry for help it could
> actually be.*

We have read many "the more...the more" pattern. Usually we believe when there is "the more", there must be another "the more" or comparative structure to complete the phrase. But here we don't see the second comparative. How should we understand the phrase quoted in bold? Does it mean the same as ***the more** we attract our own negative experiences, the more we share them*? Thank you

Comment: _The more we share them, the more we attract our negative experiences._

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Good asking practice for a first timer here. Keep it up.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELL. Please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour). Great question!

Answer (score 1):

The cited example is syntactically fine for native speakers. It might help to imagine there's an implied but unstated extra word plus comma...

> 1: *We attract our own negative experiences **more,** the more we share them*.

It's worth pointing out that all permutations of ***the more*** and ***the less*** are perfectly idiomatic when both elements of the juxtaposition are explicitly stated...

> 2: *The **more** I work the **more** I earn*
> 3: *The **more** I worry the **less** I sleep*
> 4: *The **less** I work the **less** I earn*
> 5: *The **less** I worry the **more** I sleep*

BUT if only *one* element is explicitly specified, it has to be the *second* one (regardless of whether it's ***the more*** or ***the less***), and the implicit but unstated "change of degree" in the *first* element is always ***more***...

> 6: *Global finance gets confusing, the **more** I study it* (gets ***more*** confusing)
> 7: *He talks sensibly, the **less** he drinks* (talks ***more*** sensibly)

---

It's also worth pointing out that in OP's *specific* example, the preceding sentence features a "fully specified" instance of ***the more** [details] / **the less** [sympathy].* On purely stylistic grounds it's probably better not to repeat the full construction twice in successive sentences.

Comment: Thank you very much ! The explanation is very clear!!!!